# Как провести токенизацию

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста чего не хватает.
Есть текст, в нём много строчек. Надо все строчки перевести в слова.
Насколько я понимаю, сначала надо вывести полный список, и потом к нему применить split()?

```
Ex = open('example.txt', "r") 

re.split('[^a-z]', t)
print Ex.read()
```

Выходит такая вот ошибка:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-99c4d81bbab9> in <module>()
      1 Ex = open('sentences.txt', "r")
      2 
----> 3 re.split('[^a-z]', t)
      4 print result()

NameError: name 't' is not defined
```

Upd. После небольших правок

```
Ex = open('example.txt', "r") 
data_list = list(Ex)
tokens = re.split('[^a-z]', data_list)
print Ex.read()
```

появилась новая ошибка

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-81-46f30d62d885> in <module>()
      1 Ex = open('example.txt', "r")
      2 data_list = list(Ex)
----> 3 tokens = re.split('[^a-z]', data_list)
      4 print Ex.read()

C:\Users\Dmitry\Anaconda2\lib\re.pyc in split(pattern, string, maxsplit, 
flags)
    169     """Split the source string by the occurrences of the pattern,
    170     returning a list containing the resulting substrings."""
--> 171     return _compile(pattern, flags).split(string, maxsplit)
    172 
    173 def findall(pattern, string, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Получилось пока так, ошибок нет, но и результата нет

```
Ex = open('example.txt', "r") 

s=input()
for line in Ex: print line.strip()
t = re.split('[^a-z]', s)
print t.read()
```

Comment: Вы открыли файл. Дальше предполагается, что вы прочитаете его содержимое в переменную `t`, но вы этого почему-то не делаете, и Пайтон сообщает вам, что переменная не определена.

Comment: Вторая ошибка это ошибка типа. Функция `split` хочет на вход строку, а вы ей даете список. Вам нужно прочитать весь файл в одну строку. Либо, если читаете в список или построчно, то и обрабатывайте строки в цикле.

Comment: Была одна проблема, стало две. Зачем вам регулярные выражения?

Comment: Так беру и при помощи регулярных выражений разделяю на слова..

Comment: Короче, что у Вас в файле (приведите пример строки) и что вам надо получить в итоге (приведите пример измененной строки)?

Answer (score 2):

Файл необходимо либо вчитать полностью как одну строку или читать строку за строкой, и разбивать уже полученный текст с помощью вашего выражения.

Пример построчного разбиения файла:

```
with open('example.txt', "r") as Ex:
    for line in Ex:
        print(re.split('[^A-Za-z]+', line.strip()))
```

Пример разбиения файла как одной строки:

```
with open('example.txt', "r") as Ex:
    print(re.split('[^A-Za-z]+', Ex.read().strip()))
```

Если нужно вдобавок избавиться от пустых элементов, часто возникающих при использовании `re.split`, отфильтруйте результат. В Python 3.x:

```
list( filter ( None, re.split('[^A-Za-z]+', Ex.read().strip()) ) )
```

Если нужно разбить по любым не-буквам, замените `'[^A-Za-z]+'` на

```
re.findall(r'[^\W\d_]+', line)
re.findall(r'[^\W\d_]+', Ex.read())
```

Т.е. выберите все цепочки буквенных символов.